# PDO insert statement and comma separator

Tags: php, pdo

I have:

```
INSERT INTO post(title,message) VALUES (:title,:message)
```

where `:message` value has some random text with symbols (including comma).

As the comma symbol is the separator between components of the statement:

How can i *escape* `:message` value to keep its included commas in the string context and not be interpreted as the separator?

Comment: PDO should already know that it is part of the string context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to. The whole point of using prepared statements, as you are with PDO, is that the structure of the query is sent separately from the data. This means that characters in the data are never confused for parts of the structure of the query.

You've done all you need to do to make the query safe in this regard.

Comment: Of course. Then i am pretty sure it is an error of mine when processing the query string. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

[Prepared statements my friend.](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)

**This is what php.net has to say;**

> The query only needs to be parsed (or prepared) once, but can be executed multiple time with the same or different parameters. When
> the query is prepared, the database will analyze, compile and optimize
> its plan for executing the query. For complex queries this process can
> take up enough time that it will noticeably slow down an application
> if there is a need to repeat the same query many times with different
> parameters. By using a prepared statement the application avoids
> repeating the analyze/compile/optimize cycle. This means that prepared
> statements use fewer resources and thus run faster.
>
> The parameters to prepared statements don't need to be quoted; the driver automatically handles this. If an application exclusively uses
> prepared statements, the developer can be sure that no SQL injection
> will occur (however, if other portions of the query are being built up
> with unescaped input, SQL injection is still possible).